# How would I improve this simple python class and its docstring ?

Tags: python, class, coding-style, docstring

This is a simple filter that I have been using for a project reading data over a serial connection, and thought it would be good to use it as my first attempt to write docstrings. Does anyone have any suggestions? I have been reading PEP 257. As it is a class, should the keyword arguments come after the `__init__` ?

If there is a better way to write any part of it (not only the docstrings), I would appreciate it if people could point me in the right direction.

```
class Filter(object) :
    """Return x if x is greater than min and less than max - else return None. 

    Keyword arguments:
    min -- the minimum (default 0)
    max -- the maximum (default 0)

    Notes:
    Accepts integers and integer strings
    """
    def __init__(self, min=0, max=0) :
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
    def __call__(self, input) :
        try :
            if int(input) <= self.max and int(input) >= self.min : 
                return int(input)
        except : pass
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1 is probably a better location for this question, but I based a lot of my style on [google's python style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments), which your docstring seems to conform to pretty well.  It's hard to evaluate documentation for such a simple case: I'm most grateful for documentation when it makes using a complex function or Class easy.

Comment: I completely understand. I thought that a simple example would make it easier for people to read quickly instead of getting lost in what it actually did, and thus not being able to comment, as they didn't know what the code was actually doing.

Comment: Have you considered getting critique of your interface as well as your documentation?

Comment: completely... any suggestions are most welcome

Comment: @user969617: One suggestion: don't use `max`, `min`, or `input` as variable names as doing so masks the Python builtin functions with the same names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to use pylint and pep8 to check the code conventions and common typing mistakes.